# How can i debug my rfid scan app while zebra device is in the docking station

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, datawedge, zebra-scanners

does anyone know if and how I can debug an app that runs on a Zebra MC3300XR? As soon as I put the device in the docking station to be recognized by Visual Studio via usb, I can no longer read rfid. The read function seems to be disabled then. Unfortunately I can't find anything in the Datawedge app to configure it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

In the AndroidSDK folder there is the adb.exe.

Just type adb tcpip 5555, then type adb connect "your local WLAN IP":5555 and you can debug via wlan